# Which virtual machines exist for Linux besides VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, software-rec, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

What virtual machine software is there for Linux besides VirtualBox?

Answer (score 3):

You can use for example qemu + kquemu acceleration, but VirtualBox is easier.

And you can also install VMWare (for example, [VMWare server](http://register.vmware.com/content/download.html) )

Answer (score 3):

I think most popular virtual machines for Linux are:

- [KVM (Kernel Based Virtual Machine)](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page). I guess it's also the fastest VM for Linux.
- [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page)
- [Xen](http://www.xen.org/)

There is also a GUI for manage all these VMs - [Virtual Machine Manager](http://virt-manager.et.redhat.com/).

Answer (score 2):

VMWare is available for Linux.

As far as I remember, the [server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/features.html) and [player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) versions cost nothing, but the [workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/) does have a price.

I have only used VMWare on Windows (and that was a while ago), where I found that it considerably slowed down boot times etc. I find that Virtualbox is much better, and have (rather lazily) just used it on Linux rather than bother trying VMWare.

There is also [bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) that you could have a look at as well as qemu.

If you do try the others, perhaps you could report back on how they compare: I must admit that I've basically ignored the non-Virtualbox options for quite a while.

Comment: I tried VMWare Player and qemu and they both work better than Virtual Box.

Comment: The current VMPlayer 3.x works very nicely on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [XEN](http://www.xen.org/):

> The Xen® hypervisor, the powerful open source industry standard for virtualization, offers a powerful, efficient, and secure feature set for virtualization of x86, x86_64, IA64, ARM, and other CPU architectures. It supports a wide range of guest operating systems including Windows®, Linux®, Solaris®, and various versions of the BSD operating systems.

Comment: That one is hard to install.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how resrictive your question is. Ie. what you mean by virtual. And this is something that is easily Googled. Google immediately comes up with http://virt.kernelnewbies.org/TechComparison which seems reasonably comprehensive. I used vserver for some years. That worked well, but I think the community around it may be too small for long term survival. More recently I've used VIrtualBox.