# Need advice on virtualisation software and a suitable Linux distro

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualization, linux-distributions

I'm looking for reasonably user-friendly, free virtualisation software that I can run on Windows 7. I want to install a Linux distro (though I don't know which one yet).

Can anyone recommend the virtualisation software and/or a Linux distro that would be good for virtualisation?

I'll be running this on an 64-bit Intel i7 quad-core with 6GB RAM, so I think I'll have the horse power for most things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual machines in Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/169416/virtual-machines-in-linux)

Comment: @Sathya - not really. The host OS here is Windows 7, not Linux.

Comment: @Gnoupi - woops. Read the question too fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found VirtualBox to be useful and easy.  I run Ubuntu 10.4 as the host and Windows 2000 in the Virtual Machine.  It was pretty easy to set up and did the job I wanted (running MS C++ 6.0).  VirtualBox is now supported by Oracle since their acquisition of Sun Microsystems.

Edit: Vbox can be hosted on Windows though I have not used it that way.

Edit: Vbox on windows works just as well.  Excellent way to keep good software (c++ 6.0) running in spite of MS best efforts to make it obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

The most popular choices are [Sun VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and [VMWare Server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/). Both are free. I think VBox is a little easier to jump into if you are not familiar with virtualization. The price for that, though, is that it is not as feature-rich as VMWare.

Cheers!
dafydd

Comment: Around me, at similar user competence levels and feature requirements, there is more frustration with VMware than with VirtualBox.